# Why does my GBA emulator run slow on my i7 iMac?

Tags: macos, emulation, android, game-boy-advance

I have a Game Boy Advance emulator (Visual Boy Advance) on my iMac (specs below), and it has an extremely choppy frame rate.  Gameboid on my Droid X however runs smooth as silk. What gives?

I know that Visual Boy Advance is a PPC application so Rosetta is used, but it would surprise me if that was the bottleneck.

iMac:

- 2.93 GHz Intel Core i7
- 8 GB 1333 MHz DDR3

Comment: Make sure you have the options set right; Filter to Normal, Priority to High, Vysnc off and Render Method not set to GDI in Video, etc. (Note that's the Windows menus so it might be different).

Comment: Is this phenomenon tied to a specific game, or systemwide? Certain games are emulated better than others.

Comment: You realize that [VBA-M](http://vba-m.com/) has been in active development for a while now right?  They have releases for win/*nix/mac in 32- and 64-bit flavors.  Use that instead of the old VBA "classic."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rosetta is definitely the bottleneck in this case. You're running a game that is designed for one processor in an emulator which was designed for another processor which is running in an emulator on yet another different processor.

**tl;dr**: `GBA Game > Emulator > Emulator > Computer`.  Find something Windows-based and run it in Wine, or find something written for Intel CPUs.